# How to pass in an argument to function call to change css styling?

Tags: javascript, css, function, arguments, function-calls

I want to create a function that allows me to show or hide a button by passing in an argument to the function.

```
<div class="grid">
<div id="quiz" class="centered grid__col--8">
    <h1>Awesome Quiz</h1>

    <h2 id="question" class="headline-secondary--grouped"></h2>
    <h3 id="score"></h3>

    <p id="choice0"></p>
    <button id="guess0" class="btn--default">Select Answer</button>

    <p id="choice1"></p>
    <button id="guess1" class="btn--default">Select Answer</button>

    <footer>
        <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Above I have the button element with id="guess0". I want to use a javascript function to hide that element after a certain action happens using an if...else statement.

I have tried the options below without success: (I realize that the last one is probably dumb, but I wanted to be thorough in what I have already tried.)

```
function guess0ButtonDisplay(displayStyle) {
guess0Button.style.display = '\'' + displayStyle + '\'' ;
}

function guess0ButtonDisplay(displayStyle) {
guess0Button.style.display = displayStyle;
}

function guess0ButtonDisplay(displayStyle) {
guess0Button.style.display = 'displayStyle';
}
```

Attempting to call the function:

```
guess0ButtonDisplay(none);
```

The console reported an "Uncaught ReferenceError: none is not defined" for all of the above functions when I called them and passed in the argument 'none'.

If I want to simply hide the button with "id=guess0" I can use the following function successfully:

```
function guess0ButtonDisplay() {
guess0Button.style.display = 'none';
}
```

However, I want to know if I can use one function to change the css display property value in multiple places throughout the code rather than writing separate functions to hide the element (set css: display=none;) and another function to show the element (set css: display=inline;).

Comment: I think you should use $("#guess0').hide(); if you are using jQuery, else in pure javascript var element = document.getElementById("guess0"); element.style.display = none;

Comment: That is a jQuery solution. You shouldn't recommend jQuery unless they include it as a tag or in their code.

Answer (score 0):

Pass none as a string

```
guess0ButtonDisplay('none');
```

& in the function use like this

```
function guess0ButtonDisplay(displayStyle) {
guess0Button.style.display = displayStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you'd have to call it as:

```
guess0ButtonDisplay('none');
```

with quotation marks. And use version 2 of your function:

```
function guess0ButtonDisplay(displayStyle) {
  guess0Button.style.display = displayStyle;
}
```

That said, you should really instead define a CSS class and just add/remove the class:

```
# CSS
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

// JS
function guess0ButtonDisplay(show) {
  if (show) {
    guess0Button.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    guess0Button.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

While it is a little more code, it winds up a lot cleaner because it allows you to control your CSS without having it too intermingled in your code, and allows you to also reuse the blocks.

Comment: A parent element already had a display property of 'inline-block' and overrode 'display: hidden;' when I tried to add the class 'hidden' as suggested above. I found that I could hide the element that I wanted to hide by swapping in 'visibility: hidden;' in place of 'display: none;' to the class 'hidden' in the css file. Are there any problems or disadvantages to the method I used?

Comment: The real possible problem is that if you wanted to change what "hidden" means, you have to muck with your code in several places (for example, if instead of `display: block` you want to use `visibility: hidden` or position it off-screen or something). Having your CSS in a class you toggle instead makes it a bit cleaner. If it doesn't work because of an overriding style, you could add `!important` to the rule to enforce it as well.